# Wait for element to display is not working in web driver sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am using webdriver sampler for my test, and I am waiting for a table to appear on my page which is not working,

```
var driver = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var driver_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
var start = new Date().getTime()

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.browser.get("https://<some_url>/mrlb/f4d7f910-03bf-4c6f-93aa-0d47d7ec5afd");
var attempt = 1 ;

while (new Date().getTime() - start < 5000) {
    try{
        if (WDS.browser.findElement(driver.By.className('.dataTables_wrapper.form-inline.dt-bootstrap.no-footer')).isDisplayed()) {
        WDS.log.info('Table is displayed')
        break;
    } 
} 
    catch(err){
        if (attempt < 10) {
            WDS.log.info('Attempt # ' + attempt + ', Element not found');
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000)
            attempt++
            WDS.log.info('Current Value of Attemp # ' + attempt);
        }          
}
}

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

also tried with

```
wait.until(driver.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.className('.dataTables_wrapper.form-inline.dt-bootstrap.no-footer')));
        WDS.log.info("Table displayed");
        break;
```

Also checked the css locator it is fine,

[CSS Locator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9tOx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this,

```
var driver = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var driver_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
var start = new Date().getTime()
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var wait=new driver_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20)
var exception = null

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.browser.get("https://<url>");
try {
    wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(driver.By.className('.dataTables_wrapper.form-inline.dt-bootstrap.no-footer')))
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
}

catch (error){
    exception = error;
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
}
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

reference: [Web Driver Rules to follow](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)